# How to annotate with multiple columns using mplcursors

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors, plot-annotations

Below is code for a scatter plot annotated using `mplcursors` which uses two columns, labeling the points by a third column.

How can two values from two columns from a single dataframe be selected for annotation text in a single text box?

When instead of only `"name"` in the annotation text box, I would like both `"height"` and `"name"` to show in the annotation text box. Using `df[['height', 'name']]` does not work.

How can this be achieved otherwise?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [("Alice", 163, 54),
     ("Bob", 174, 67),
     ("Charlie", 177, 73),
     ("Diane", 168, 57)],
    columns=["name", "height", "weight"])

df.plot.scatter("height", "weight")
mplcursors.cursor(multiple = True).connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text((df["name"])[sel.target.index]))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `df.loc[sel.target.index, ["name", 'height']].to_string()`: correctly select the columns and row with `.loc` and then create a `string` with `.to_string()`
- **Tested in `python 3.8`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, `pandas 1.3.1`, and `jupyterlab 3.1.4`**
- In `mplcursors v0.5.1`, `Selection.target.index` is deprecated, use `Selection.index` instead.

  - `df.iloc[x.index, :]` instead of `df.iloc[x.target.index, :]`

```py
from mplcursors import cursor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# for interactive plots in Jupyter Lab, use the following magic command, otherwise comment it out
%matplotlib qt 

df = pd.DataFrame([('Alice', 163, 54), ('Bob', 174, 67), ('Charlie', 177, 73), ('Diane', 168, 57)], columns=["name", "height", "weight"])

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x="height", y="weight", c='tab:blue')
cr = cursor(ax, hover=True, multiple=True)

cr.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text((df.loc[sel.index, ["name", 'height']].to_string())))
plt.show()
```

[image]